# How to trim content AND retain HTML?

Tags: php, functions, excerpt

I have an element that use to pull in `the_excerpt` but we wanted to retain the HTML. So we started using `the_content`. Now the amount it's pulling in is too long. I have tried using `wp_trim_words` but that strips the HTML, essentially making it the same as using `the_excerpt`.

Is there anyway to limit the amount of content displayed from a page and retain the HTML for *just this one instance*? I do not want to effect `the_excerpt` or `the_content` permanently/site-wide.

Comment: Have you considered what happens when you trim the HTML content? This will potentially break your HTML structure. Imagine the trim happens right in the middle of an ordered list's items, so you will have no `</li>` and / or `</ol>`.

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147898/how-to-set-character-limit-on-the-content-and-the-excerpt-in-wordpress . Hope you will get your solution.
Thanks